# Plothraw PARIGP (or similar) doesn't work (latexit crash)

Tags: plot, graphics, latex, pari-gp

I'm a new user of PARI/GP, and after writing my script, I wanted to make a graph of it. As my function take an integer and return a number, it's closer to a sequence. Actually, I didn't know how to do it, so I read the documentation of PARI/GP, and after that I made some test in order to obtain a graph from a list.

After reading an answer in stackoverflow ([Plotting multiple lists in Pari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230956/plotting-multiple-lists-in-pari)), I wanted to test with the following code:

```
plothraw([0..200], apply(i->cos(i*3*Pi/200), [0..200]), 0);
```

But when I do it, it tries to open something on latexit, but then it crash and give me a problem report.

I didn't even know that I had an app named latextit, maybe it was install during the installation of PARI/GP. Anyway, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. PARI/GP definitely doesn't install `latexit`.
2. The way hi-res graphics work on the Win32 version of PARI/GP is to write down an Enhanced Metafile (.EMF) in a temp directory and ask the system to
   "open" it. When you installed `latexit` it probably created an association in the registry to let it open .EMF files
3. `i3Pi` does not mean what you think, it just creates a new variable with that name. You want `i * 3 * Pi` instead.
4. The following constructions both work in my setup

   ```
   plothraw([0..200], apply(i->cos(i*3*Pi/200), [0..200]), 0);
   plothraw([0..200], apply(i->cos(i*3*Pi/200), [0..200]), 1);
   ```

(the second one being more readable because a red line is drawn between successive points; I have trouble seeing the few tiny blue dots)

5. Instead of `apply`, you can use a direct constructor as in

   ```
     vector(201, i, cos((i-1) * 3 * Pi / 200))
   ```

which of course can be computed more efficiently as

```
     real( powers(exp(3*I*Pi/200), 200) )
```

(of course, it doesn't matter here, but compare both commands at precision `\p10000` or so ...)